# SQL syntax to merge two tables?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables I would like to merge as follows.

Table a:

```
columns :a1     a2
data    :aaa    a2
         bbb    b2
```

Table b:

```
columns :a1     b2
data    :aaa    a3
         ccc    c3
```

The final desired output table would include the following:

Table final:

```
columns :a1     a2    b2
data    :aaa    a2    a3
         bbb    b2
         ccc          c3
```

Comment: What database?? What version?? What datatypes are your columns?? What do you want to JOIN the two tables on???

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
       a.a1, a.a2, b.b2
FROM 
       a 
FULL JOIN 
       b ON a.a1 = b.a1
```

Comment: it is sometimes called `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Read documentation of your DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Test data
with TableA(a1, a2) as
(
  select 'aaa', 'a1' union all
  select 'bbb', 'b2'
),
TableB(a1, b2) as
(
  select 'aaa', 'a3' union all
  select 'ccc', 'c3'
)


select
  coalesce(A.a1, B.A1) as a1,
  A.a2,
  B.b2
from TableA as A
  full outer join TableB as B
    on A.a1 = B.a1
```

Result:

```
a1   a2   b2
---- ---- ----
aaa  a1   a3
ccc  NULL c3
bbb  b2   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to`JOIN` the two tables with something like

```
SELECT a.a1, a.a2, b.b2 FROM table_a a 
JOIN table_b b ON a.a1 = b.a1
```

Depending on what you need, you may need a `lEFT JOIN` (sometimes called an `OUTER JOIN`). The actual syntax also depends on what database you are using. This example will work on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.a1, a.a2, b.b2
INTO NewTable
FROM a,b
Where b.a1=a.a1
```

Comment: Please don't use the "old-style" legacy JOINs by just enumerating the tables in the FROM clause - you should switch to using the proper ANSI JOIN syntax - `FROM a INNER JOIN b ON ......`

Comment: this example fails on the case when records are in one table but not the other such as the examples of BBB and CCC given in the OP and would only return one record {AAA, a2, a3}

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
       ISNULL(a.a1, b.a1) AS a1, a.a2, b.b2
FROM 
       a 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
       b ON a.a1 = b.a1
```

For more info on Outer Joins in general see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx